# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_sensitive'

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.9

I am getting error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_sensitive'

while i was working on a downloaded project where i need to import a file (settings_sensitive.py).

I double checked all the possible errors that could be there.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 

settings_sensitive = BASE_DIR + '/source/settings_sensitive.py' 
if os.path.isfile(settings_sensitive): 
    from settings_sensitive import *
```

[image]

Comment: Post code and error message as **text**

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: @barbsan `settings_sensitive = BASE_DIR + '/source/settings_sensitive.py'
if os.path.isfile(settings_sensitive):
    from settings_sensitive import *` **I have also attached the image in case you need to go through the directory tree or the code of the file.**

Comment: @BhuvaneshPrajapati can you also post the `BASE_DIR` path for us to see>

Comment: @DevanshuMisra `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
#and then from settings_sensitive import *   or  import settings_sensitive
```

Comment: i already did this...and this is why i am getting this error.

Comment: can you try  
    
    import settings_sensitive

Comment: `from . import settings_sensitive` this worked for me.